# Can't get my Leaflet popup to display correctly

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am building a web map that uses an OSM base map and a GeoJSON layer that has polygons with attributes.

I can't get the attributes to display.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [31.804632, -99.042733],
  zoom: 15
});

// Add Open Street Map as base map
var osm = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);


// ADDING THE PROPERTY MAP
function addDataToMap(data, map) {
    var dataLayer = L.geoJson(data);
    dataLayer.addTo(map);
}


$.getJSON("http://www.website.com/web_map_geojson_test.geojson", function(data) { addDataToMap(data, map); });


test = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);

test.addTo(map).eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.land_val);
});
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise on what is trying to be achieved? Do you want to display a popup at a specific location with some text in it? Or what exactly are these "attributes"?

Comment: The two lines at the bottom will probably execute before the GeoJSON data has been retrieved - put them in the success function of the `$.getJSON` call.

Comment: Yes, I want to display a popup on the polygon that is clicked.  For the test case I am just trying to pull one of the attributes ("land_val") which is just a number.  Later, I might add strings and other numbers.

Comment: @peeebeee I did this but it still doesn't work: `$.getJSON("http://www.website.com/web_map_geojson_test.geojson", function(data) {
  addDataToMap(data, map);
  
  test = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);

  test.addTo(map).eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.land_val);
});`

Comment: You need to share more code and data sample for people to be able to help you. Make sure you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ideally also provide a live reproduction example, e.g. using code snippet, Plunker, JSFiddle, JSBin, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper way to do that thanks to `L.geoJson` and `onEachFeature`. You can check documentation here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

```
var geojson;

$.getJSON('http://www.website.com/web_map_geojson_test.geojson', function(data) {
    geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var popup = L.popup({className: 'popup_class'}).setContent(layer.feature.properties.land_val);
            layer.bindPopup(popup);
        }
    });

    geojson.addTo(map);
});
```

Check the console when you click your layer to see if there is any error.